# How do I combine these strings to input into the PlaySound method

Tags: c++, string

I have this code that gets my project's path without the .exe file at the end:

```
string ExePath() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    string::size_type pos = string( buffer ).find_last_of( "\\/" );
    return string( buffer ).substr( 0, pos);
}
```

When I use this ExePath() method, I get `c:/blah/blah/Debug` and the `.wav` file I want to play is in that folder.

So I need to call `PlaySound(/* path to wav file */, NULL, SND_ASYNC);` but I cant combine `ExePath()` and `MySound.wav` by simply concatenating them, I am getting errors.

How can I do this?

I am saying: `PlaySound(ExePath().c_str() + "MySound.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC);` but I am getting an error saying under the `MySound.wav` part saying **Error: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type**

Comment: How are you concatenating them ?

Comment: In the first argument of the playsound function I say: `ExePath() + "MySound.wav"`

Comment: You should indicate that, and the errors you're getting, too. The errors might event come from the `PlaySound` function.

Comment: The file is in my Debug folder. I know the name of it. And I can get the path to the debug folder by using ExePath(). So know I need to supply this path to PlaySound by combining ExePath() and the name of the sound file (which I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I used this code:

`PlaySound(ExePath().append("MySound.wav").c_str(), NULL, SND_ASYNC);`

Comment: Alternatively, `PlaySound((ExePath()+"MySound.wav").c_str()`, but I kinda like yours better.